# Питон удаляет не все пробелы из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, list

Я создал функцию, которая должна убирать пробелы в списках. Она работает, но *частично*.

```
my_list = [1, " ", 2, " ", " ", 3, " ", " ", " ", 4, " ", " ", " ", " ", 5] # Мой список

def remove_spaces (list_): # Функция, которая удаляет пробелы из списка

    for i in list_: # Через этот цикл я перебераю список на наличие пробелов и удаляю их
        if i == " ":
            list_.remove(i)
        else:
            pass

    return list_ # Возвращаю изменённый список

print (remove_spaces(my_list)) # Вывожу на экран

# Должно получиться: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# Но он возвращает: [1, 2, 3, 4, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 5]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такая проблема появляется при итерации списка и одновременном удалении элементов из него, так как индекс уменьшается, особенно это наглядно видно, если попытаться взаимодействовать с элементами списка.

Ниже пример кода, который выбросит ошибку:

```
my_list = [1, " ", 2, " ", " ", 3, " ", " ", " ", 4, " ", " ", " ", " ", 5]
# в ходе итерации проитерирует по 7 элементам и выбросит ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
for i, j in enumerate(my_list):
    print(i, j)
    if j == " ":
        my_list.remove(i)
```

Есть несколько способов решить проблему:

Первый способ создать копию списка, по нему итерировать и удалять элементы из другого

```
my_list = [1, " ", 2, " ", " ", 3, " ", " ", " ", 4, " ", " ", " ", " ", 5]


def remove_spaces(list_):
    iter_list = list_.copy()
    for i in iter_list:
        if i == " ":
            list_.remove(i)

    return list_


print(remove_spaces(my_list))
```

Второй способ создать новый список по условию и его вернуть.

```
my_list = [1, " ", 2, " ", " ", 3, " ", " ", " ", 4, " ", " ", " ", " ", 5]


def remove_spaces(list_):
    new_list = []
    for i in list_:
        if i != " ":
            new_list.append(i)

    return new_list


print(remove_spaces(my_list))
```

Через генератор-выражение:

```
my_list = [1, " ", 2, " ", " ", 3, " ", " ", " ", 4, " ", " ", " ", " ", 5]


def remove_spaces(list_):
    return [i for i in list_ if i != " "]


print(remove_spaces(my_list))
```